# MySQL query performance on two indexes + sorting

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I'm implementing the following access policy: a `User` can access a `Resource` if he created it, belongs to the `Resource`'s group members or if the resource is publicly available.

Here is my DB structure (tables are MyISAM):

```
User (1K-10K Users)
  id
  nickame
  …
  index user_name(id, nickname)
Group (1K)
  id
  …
Resource (10K-100K)
  id
  user_id
  access_type (int)
  group_id
  created (int/timestamp)
  …
  indexes by_user(user_id, created), by_group(access_type, group_id, created), public(access_type, created)
User_Group (5K-20K)
  user_id
  group_id
  membership_type (int)
  index user_group(user_id, membership_type, group_id)
```

The conditions to grant access are implemented this way:
* The `User` is the creator of the `Resource` (`user_id = <his id>`, whatever access_type is)
* Or the ressource is publicly available: `Resource.access_id = 3`
* Or the ressource is shared in a group and the User is accepted as "member" of this group:
** `Resource.access_id = 2` (shared in a group)
** `Ressource.group_id` matches a `User_Group`'s `group_id`
** this `User_Group`'s `user_id` matches the User's id
** this `User_Group`'s `membership_type` is 1, 2 or 3 (accepted member or group moderator/admin)

My question is: what is the most efficient way to list the `Resources` (and the `Resource` creator's `nickname`) that are accessible to the User when we have his ID. And ordered by the Resource's `created` timestamp.

My best attempt so far is to use an `UNION` that allows using both `by_user` and `by_group` indexes, but might struggle in the sorting afterwards:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
  a.*, user.nickname
FROM (
  ( SELECT resource.* FROM resource WHERE user_id = '000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' )
UNION
  ( SELECT resource.* FROM resource WHERE access_type = 3 )
UNION
  ( SELECT resource.* FROM resource
   INNER JOIN user_group ON (access_type = 2 AND user_group.group_id = resource.group_id)
   WHERE user_group.user_id = '000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    AND user_group.type IN (1, 2, 3)
  )
) a
LEFT JOIN user ON (user.id = a.user_id)
ORDER BY created DESC;
```

The `EXPLAIN` output tells me it uses the indexes for both `SELECT`s and finishes with a `type: ALL / Using filesort` for the `ORDER BY` on `UNION`-ed rows. But if I want to order and limit, this can get heavy, I guess, since there is no index on `UNION`-ed tuples.

The other possibility is a simpler query with a subquery for the `Groups` the `User` is in:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
  resource.*, user.nickname
FROM resource
LEFT JOIN user ON (user.id = resource.user_id) 
WHERE user_id = '000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
  OR access_type = 3
  OR (access_type = 2 AND group_id IN
   ( SELECT group_id FROM user_group USE INDEX (`user_group`)
   WHERE user_id = '000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND type IN (1, 2, 3)
   )
  )
ORDER BY created DESC;
```

But here the `EXPLAIN` tells me it won't use the index and performs a selection `type: ALL / Using where; using filesort` in the `Resource` table, witch is what I'm trying to avoid. If I try to `FORCE INDEX(by_user, by_group)`, it is starts by merging both indexes `type: index_merge / Using sort_union(by_user,by_group); Using where; Using filesort`, which can be costly too.

Any better idea ? This request may be very frequently called…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a second join will better utilize indexes here versus the subquery you suggested (just need to add a DISTINCT to avoid duplicates).

```
  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT
         resource.*, user.nickname
    FROM resource
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = resource.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_group ON user_group.user_id = user.id AND user_group.type IN (1, 2, 3)
    WHERE user_id = '000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       OR access_type = 3
      OR (access_type = 2 AND group_id IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY created DESC;
```

Any time your primary WHERE clause is a sequence of OR's, the ideal EXPLAIN result will be some type of index_merge.  However, you are correct that sort_union is the slowest of these.  If you read up on [index_merge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html), particularly the sub parts about each type of merge, it becomes clear that the OR pieces of your WHERE clause need to reference all parts of a key, otherwise you'll get a sort_union.  So you should get a better EXPLAIN result if you had resource indexes:

```
Resource (10K-100K)
id
user_id
access_type (int)
group_id
created (int/timestamp)
…
indexes 
    just_user(user_id),
    by_user(user_id, created),
    just_access(access_type),
    just_access_group(access_type, group_id),
    by_group(access_type, group_id, created),
    public(access_type, created)
```

I recognize that this seems to contradict that you get left prefixes as indexes for free when you do multi-part keys but it seems the index_merge algorithm can't (yet?) utilize those partial prefix indexes.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read & answer. I'll run some test when I get to work on this.